# Local database doesn't store my data

Tags: c#, datagrid, local-database

I created a local database in C#, actually I didn't write any special code to show data on my text boxes and other components. In Server Explorer I just use my favorite component for each field and then drag them on my form and  add two buttons. one for make a new record and  other to save data.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.anbarBindingSource.AddNew();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.anbarBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.myDataSet);
    //  this.anbarTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet);
}
```

but sometimes after rebuilding the project my datagrid does not show my data, even I select "copy if newer"  for copy to output directory property of my database and when I use "do not copy" I get an exception.

sometimes it shows me my data but when I add a new query by selecting add query on datagrid and click on querybuilder it does not show my data on data grid.

Comment: What type of database do you use and how do you load the data? The code you provided does not explain the problem you describe...

Comment: as I said I used local database which use sqlserver. I made a local database then I define my table and its field. I made a dataset then drag its fields on my form and they show me data but I have the problem that I DESCRIBED BEFORE